# App's calendar no longer an option for new appointment in Windows calendar app

Tags: uwp, calendar, windows-10-universal

My UWP app creates a calendar and adds appointments to it. I want the user to be able to interact with the calendar, including adding appointments, in the system calendar app, which was possible in the past. My app was notified of these changes using `AppointmentStoreChangeTracker`.

At some point (in the past year?), that changed, and the system calendar app no longer shows my app's calendar as an option for adding new appointments. The calendar app still shows appointments from my calendar, and still allows editing the appointments it shows, but it doesn't show up in any of the dropdown lists to select the calendar for a new appointment.

Here's the code I'm using to create an appointment:

```
AppointmentCalendar appCalendar = await appointmentStore.CreateAppointmentCalendarAsync(calname);
appCalendar.OtherAppReadAccess = AppointmentCalendarOtherAppReadAccess.Full;
appCalendar.OtherAppWriteAccess = AppointmentCalendarOtherAppWriteAccess.Limited;
appCalendar.CanCreateOrUpdateAppointments = true;
appCalendar.SummaryCardView = AppointmentSummaryCardView.System;
appCalendar.DisplayColor = calcolor;
await appCalendar.SaveAsync();
```

I've tried fiddling around with some of the access parameters, but with no luck. Was this feature silently removed? Is it possible to allow the user to add appointments to my app's calendar using the system calendar app?

Edit to add screenshots:
For example, my app creates a calendar called "Scheduled Tasks" (red). It is visible in the Calendar app:

[image: Visible in Calendar app]

It does not show up as an option in the target calendar drop down for a new appointment. Only the three Outlook account calendars do.

[image: Not visible in new appointment calendar drop down]

Comment: Do you means that you could not use the above code to create app's calendar in system calendar app. But in my test, the above code works well.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT This code creates a calendar, and appointments on that calendar show up in the system calendar app, but that calendar isn't an option for new appointments. It doesn't show up in the dropdown for which calendar the appointment is supposed to go on.

Comment: I will test creating appointment in the app calendar.

Comment: I could add appointment  to the app's calendar, but i don't really understand `show up in the dropdown` mean. You could share a screenshot to describe.

Comment: I added some screenshots. Does that make sense now, @NicoZhu-MSFT?